# how many time zones are there?

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I'm not sure whether this is an SO question but still would like to know the answer.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) says there are about 40 time zones, but when I invoke the `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` method in c# it returns a list of 101 elements.

Is the wiki article outdated (though it "was last modified on 26 April 2012 at 05:11") or are there any additional time zones?

Comment: ... Do not forget day light saving!

Comment: Last modified at 05:11 - but which time zone?

Comment: @Ed Heal, that makes about 80, even less, but not 101

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no one answer - it depends on what time zone database you're interested in. Using `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones` will use the Windows time zones... if you use [tzdb](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) you're likely to see a lot more.

(The current [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) version returns 575 time zone IDs, for example, although that includes Etc/GMT+9, Etc/GMT+10 etc.)

Comment: Do you know where all this come from? I know that here in Brazil, not all countries have day light savings, which makes some countries, for 3 months a year, 1 hour different of the rest. This means Brazil have two Time Zones, am I right? Still, 575 sounds like a lot.

Comment: @Andre: No, Brazil has one time zone, which changes its offset from UTC during the year. (Actually, there may be more than one time zone if there are regional variations, but that's a different matter.) I'm not sure you mean by "where all this come from" but if you follow the tzdb link in my answer that will get you to the IANA site which currently hosts all the data...

Comment: Hummm, thanks! By "where all this come from", I meant: there are 207 ONU members. Ok, some non recognized countries, some countries with more than one time zone. But 575 is more than double the number of countries. Why so many?

Comment: I did follow the link, thanks. I got curious about this, but I can only download when I get home....

Comment: @Andre: Well, in answer to another question, I've just looked at the *10* time zone regions for Indiana alone. There are 165 beginning with "America" (although not all of those are the US, of course.)

Comment: @Andre - A lot of it comes from the fact that there are historical changes to time zone boundaries to consider.  While an individual zone can change its rules at any time (and many have), if a particular sub region decides to follow a different set of rules than the whole timezone, that fragments the zones.  Indiana is a great example.  Almost the whole state is on Eastern time now, but since so many areas switched from Central to Eastern and on/off DST at different times, there now 11 time zones in the tzdb.

Comment: One point I forgot to mention, the TZDB creates new zones when necessary - but only for historical changes made since 1970.  So there could be quite many more in some other "expanded" database - if one were to exist.